# Unable to deploy wlapp file, null source exception

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am trying to deploy wlapp file using my worklight console. After uploading file it is giving an error. "Failed to deploye 'xxx.wlapp' null source".

Adapters are getting deployed, but wlapp file is not.

Worklight Version : 6.1

Comment: When did this start? did it work in the past? what was changed since the last time it worked? where does it happen (dev environment vs production)?

Comment: It is happening in production environment, I have created new project and it is not allowed me to deploy

Comment: Did you deploy the war file? A new project will have a different authenticationConfig. If you deploy only its app and not the war it may not be recognized.

Comment: I have deployed war file, and also deployed all adapters from my console.

Comment: Edit the question with the server logs

Comment: I don't have access to server logs as of now, but its giving me PersistencyException in the logs yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where the error lies. But when I have changed the jar file of mysql connector from version 5.1.6 to 5.1.28 and redeployed the project, all thing is working fine.

I am able to deploy my application as well as all adapters. Now all thing is working fine.